# Can I efficiently write a redirect using .htaccess if domain stays the same, but new website has slightly different url structure?

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I have an old site with thousands of products and some SEO ranking and I wanted to redirect URLs using `.htaccess`, hopefully without manually writing thousands of 301 redirect entries.

The domain stays the same but url structure is different

**Old  website**

`example.com/category/sub-category/2350-Product-Name` (URL has an *id* and Capitalized letters)

**New website**

`example.com/different-category/different-subcategory/product-name` (URL has no *id* and no lowercase letters)

if I used the code below, would it be enough for a successful redirect?

```
# 301 Redirect URLs.
Redirect 301 /example.com/category/subcategory /example.com/different-category/different-subcategory
```

I found this code in another thread, which, if I understand correctly, redirects to category/subcategory that can consist of the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ (underscore) or - (hyphen), but I'm not sure how to piece this all together

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+/[\w-]+/)$
```

Comment: "url has no id and no lowercase letters" - presumably you mean "no uppercase letters" (or consists solely of lowercase letters)? How many category + subcategory combinations do you have? This would seem to determine how many rules you would need in `.htaccess`.

Comment: you need to use RewriteMap .... https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html

Answer (score 1):

### Redirects vs RedirectMatch vs RewriteCond & RewriteRule & RewriteMap

Redirects work for changing a url on the host, but don't know the host.

```
Redirect "/foo.html" "/bar.html"
Redirect "/docs/" "http://new.example.com/docs/"
# UPPERCASE to lowercase
Redirect "/category/sub-category/Product-2350/" "/new/product-2350"
Redirect "/category/sub-category/Product-2351/" "/new/product-2351"
Redirect "/category/sub-category/Product-2352/" "/new/product-2352"
```

RedirectMatch gives Regex almost RewriteRule but no functions, server / logic conditions.

```
RedirectMatch "^/(puppies|canines)/(.*)" "/dogs/$2"
```

or

```
RedirectMatch "^/CATEGORY/sub-category1/(.*)" "/new-category1/$1"
RedirectMatch "^/CATEGORY/sub-category2/(.*)" "/new-category2/$1"
```

RewriteMap has the to lowercase function you need, If you have many products.

```
#writes a lowercase version of itself.

RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteRule "(.*)" "${lc:$1}" [R]
```